# AG-Grid Cell Interdependence

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have a simple AG-Grid + Angular 5 table setup and would like AG Grid to perform the following calculation in the same row.

**Formula**

a * b = c

b = c / a

I am not very successful in using valueGetters, though. I believe I end up with some kind of ping pong effect. No errors are thrown, but as soon as I attempt to modify either b or c, I get strange results.

I'm listing my code snippets below. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this one?


**app.component.html**

```
<ag-grid-angular 
    #agGrid style="width: 100%; height: 350px;" 
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [showToolPanel]="showToolPanel"
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
    [rowData]="rowData">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  private columnDefs;
  private rowData;
  private defaultColDef;

  constructor() {


    this.columnDefs = [
      { headerName: 'a', field: 'a', editable: false },
      { 
        headerName: 'b', 
        field: 'b',
        valueGetter: this.numCalc
      },
      {
        headerName: 'c',
        field: 'c',
        valueGetter: this.resCalc
      }
    ];

    this.rowData = [
      { a: 10, b: 1, c: 10 },
      { a: 20, b: 2, c: 40 },
      { a: 30, b: 3, c: 90 }
    ];

    this.defaultColDef = { editable: true }
  }


  resCalc(params) {
    return params.data.a * params.data.b;
  }

  numCalc(params) { 
    return params.data.c / params.data.a;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use [transaction](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/#transactions) instead.

Below is a sample gridOptions for your case:

```
this.gridOptions = <GridOptions> {
  getRowNodeId: params => params.a,
  onCellEditingStopped: params => {
    const { a } = params.node.data;
    if (params.column.getColId() === 'b') {
      const data = { a, b: parseInt(params.value, 10), c: a * params.value };
      this.gridOptions.api.updateRowData({ update: [data] })
    } else if (params.column.getColId() === 'c') {
      const data = { a, b: params.value / a, c: parseInt(params.value, 10) };
      this.gridOptions.api.updateRowData({ update: [data] })
    } 
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will give your approach a try.

Comment: No worries, please note that you should remove your valueGetter as well to avoid confusion.